# blowFIsh data store in mysql database

Tags: mysql, encryption, store, password-protection, blowfish

I am using a blowfish encryted function:

```
class Blowfish {

private $key;
private $iv;

public function __construct($key, $iv) {
    $this->key = $key;
    $this->iv = $iv;
}

public function encrypt($data) {
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $this->key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $this->iv);
}

public function decrypt($data) {
    return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $this->key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $this->iv);
}}
```

Now when I am encrypted something with this function like:

```
$blowfish = new blowfish('DfRgBWE4Y4T7UgTWEdFP1Y', '85440934');
echo $pass = $blowfish -> encrypt('12345');
```

which should displays --> '  ìI”‹YR” '
but I can't save it in database table. My table structure is like:

```
`Password` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf32 NOT NULL
```

But every time I try to insert it, the insertion is like " ?I??YR? "
what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to not store (potentially) binary, i.e. non-AlphaNumeric data, in an SQL database, especially not inside varchar(..) which will mess things up when you try to look at the the data.

Instead, either Base64 or HEX encode it, HEX is probably the better option, for HEX it is very easy and native for MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO table SET Password = HEX(?)
```

The `?` is a placeholder for your Blowfish result

To pick up the binary data from the database do:

```
INSERT UNHEX(Password) FROM table
```